# What role/policy I can map for PostgreSQL USER so that he can change his existing password

Tags: postgresql, change-password

What role/policy/command I can use/map for PostgreSQL USER so that he can change on his own existing password?

```
CREATE USER abcd with ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'P@wd123!';
GRANT rds_iam, app_readonly TO abcd;
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. A user can always change his own password.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. I am using pgAdmin as a client tool to connect to PostgreSQL. I could not find that option. Should we execute any command to change the pwd @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin. I plain SQL you [can use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) `alter user current_user with password ...` or in `psql` you can use the more secure `\password` meta-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dialog to change the password of the currently connected user securely with pgAdmin4: Select the server in the tree view, then select "Object" / "Change Password..." from the menu.